# Firefox-Addon: How do i overwrite a UI function?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Actually i would like to modify the **replaceWord** function of the **spellchecker**.

I tried (in my own firefox extension) **onInit**:

```
original_replaceWord = InlineSpellCheckerUI.replaceWord;

InlineSpellCheckerUI.replaceWord = function()
{
    // things i would like to do (i.e. set the Cursor to another spot in the editor) 

    // call of the original function
    return original_replaceWord.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

But this didn't seem to work, because this function was not called when i replaced a missspelled word.

**How do i find the right function? Which one do i need to overwrite?**

thx for any suggestions

Comment: See the source of InlineSpellCheckerUI at http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/toolkit/content/inlineSpellCheckUI.js and try to find the function you need to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try this</strike>: (this is wrong. see the update below)

```
original_replaceWord = InlineSpellCheckerUI.replaceWord;

InlineSpellCheckerUI.prototype.replaceWord = function()
{
    // things i would like to do (i.e. set the Cursor to another spot in the editor) 

    // call of the original function
    return original_replaceWord.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

---

**UPDATE**

[`InlineSpellCheckerUI`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/toolkit/content/inlineSpellCheckUI.js) does not have the `replaceWord` function. The `replaceWord` function is defined in the [`nsIInlineSpellChecker`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/editor/txtsvc/public/nsIInlineSpellChecker.idl) interface which is realized by the [`mozInlineSpellChecker`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/extensions/spellcheck/src/mozInlineSpellChecker.cpp) class in C++.

So you cannot override the `replaceWord` function. However, you can try overriding the `replaceMisspelling` function in `InlineSpellCheckerUI` using the code below. I think it should serve your purpose.

```
let original_replaceMisspelling = InlineSpellCheckerUI.replaceMisspelling;

InlineSpellCheckerUI.replaceMisspelling = function()
{
    // things i would like to do (i.e. set the Cursor to another spot in the editor) 

    // call of the original function
    return original_replaceMisspelling.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I commented the original function out, but i still was able to replace misspelled words. Could it be that the spellchecking mechanism uses another function?

Comment: as i thought i was overwriting the wrong function - this did the trick. Thank you very much!